# How do I manage energy efficiently?

Tags: glitch-2011

I keep running out of energy and food.

Comment: This is kind of open ended, for that I apologize, and welcome help in focusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating food (which restores energy) is the most important endeavor in the game.  More food means more energy, which means more playtime.  (Running out of energy may not *completely* stop you from playing the game, but bopping back and forth to Hell isn't much fun and ruins your Mood, so there's not much point.)

Early in the game, the most accessible food to create is the humble [Sammich](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Sammich).  Creating sammiches requires [Meat](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Meat) (from [Piggies](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Piggy)), [Grain](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Grain) (from [Chickens](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Chicken)), and [Allspice](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Allspice) (from [Spice Plants](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Spice_Plant)).  To combine them, you'll need [EZ Cooking I](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/EZ_Cooking_I), [Cheffery I](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Cheffery_I), and [Spice Milling](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Spice_Milling), plus the tools which go with them (a [Knife & Board](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Knife_and_Board), [Frying Pan](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Frying_Pan), and [Spice Mill](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Spice_Mill), respectively).

With nothing more than the base skills, you'll regain barely more energy than you put into it (petting and nibbling a piggy, squeezing five chickens, harvesting spice, and putting them together is likely to run you almost 20 energy, compared to the 29 you get from eating the sammich), but it's still over parity, so the more you make the better off you'll be.

Even better, learning [Animal Kinship](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Animal_Kinship) skills and higher levels of the base skills will dramatically improve your effectiveness.  Bigger harvests, lower energy costs, and access to more powerful recipes will have you brimming with energy in no time!

Answer (score 2):

1. Meditation
2. Try to break up your gaming sessions between game days (since you get a refresh every day), instead of one long session.